# How is it that 1 GB (1,073,741,824) is worth 1 billion bytes roughly yet it is also within the 4 byte range where 32 bits = 4 bytes?

Tags: memory, byte

How is it so that 1 GB (1,073,741,824) is worth 1 billion bytes roughly yet it is also within the 4 byte range where 32 bits = 4 bytes & 8 bits = 1 byte with 1,073,741,824 being a 30 bit number?

Comment: because max value which can be stored in the 32bit signed integer is
2,147,483,647. (1073741824 can be stored in 10digits digital or 6 digit base 36 number (HRA0HS)).

Comment: Imagine you write on the paper 10000000000 ships. 10000000000 ships will not fit in that paper, but the number - yes.

Comment: Are you asking how you can represent large numbers with only 4 bytes?

Comment: @gregory yes i am

Comment: Sry, I've added another answer -- hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the difference between GB and GiB. One is a multiple of a thousand, the other is a multiple of one thousand and twenty four.

Context:

Bit is a portmanteau of "**bi**nary digi**t**." It represents one value of two possibles states (e.g. True/False).

Eight bits grouped together is called a byte. Why eight? Because historically a byte was the number of bits used to encode a single character of text on a computer. Want to represent the letter "A"; then you'll need a byte.

With those brief definitions, we see that 4 bytes = 32 bits because 8 * 4 = 32. Likewise we understand the giga in 1 giga-bytes = 8 billion bits.

Now here's the wrinkle: these "grouping" names (e.g. kilo, mega, giga) can be based on another metric other than the decimal one.  Another such metric is the binary one.  Starting with an initial grouping of 1024 bits, confusingly called a "kilobyte" because its size is close to a thousand, we can appropriate the term "giga" to be 1,073,741,824 bits, since it is a multiple of the base grouping (1024^3).

Starting roughly in 1980s, these sizing terms were purposely confused (for marketing purposes) and confusing. In late 90s, the International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC) tried to rectify this situation with standardized terms: abbreviations distinguish the metric being used: KB (1000) vs. KiB (1024), GB (1000^3) vs. GiB (1024^3).

Answer (score 1):

Two raised to n bits gives you the possible values some storage can represent:

```
1 bit gives you two possible values: 0 or 1. 

2 bits gives you four values: 00, 11, 10, 01.  

3 bits gives you eight values: 000, 111, 001, 010, 100, 011, 110, 101.
...

32 bits gives you 2^32 or 4,294,967,296 possible values.
```

If you want to represent a negative number with this storage, then you'll have to use a bit for the +/- sign.  That gives you half that range for negative numbers and the other half for the positive (I skimming the details with respects to zero, but you get the idea).  This is why unsigned INTs are double the size of signed ones.

storage != representation. And, this is where the topic of encoding begins...